# DataTable.Select("Bla='Blablabla'").Count Returns 'Count' is not a member of 'System.Array' Exception

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5

I'm trying to access the Count Property on the array of rows returned by the datatables select method, this is after converting the Web Project to 3.5

Answer (score 7):

Use `.Length` instead.

Comment: ok but the codebase already uses .count in alot of places and was originally working.... am I missing a reference or something

Comment: Odd.. arrays have never had a .Count property. I wonder if that used to be a 'hack' in the system that they had to remove to avoid conflicted with IEnumerable.count

Comment: in msdn when looking at the System.Array members/properties if you select 2.0 as the framework there is no count property but if you select 3.5 it appears.

Comment: Because arrays implement IEnumerable, and in 3.5 IEnumerable and  .Count extension.

Comment: And you don't want to rely on that, because it means actually iterating over the array and counting the elements, rather than just looking it up.

Comment: Just remember that .Length is 0-based and .Count is 1-based.  If an Array contains [Steve|Tom|George] then .Length() will return 2 and .Count() will return 3.

Answer (score 7):

I was missing `<add namespace="System.Linq"/>` from my web.config

Comment: system.linq is not supported in .net 2.0  for some OS to be sure his assembly will run on most OS using .net 2.0 as target framework , and doing .Length instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the vbproj file , add the following in references ItemGroup

```
<Reference Include="System.Core" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
```